# Animate blur filter with GSAP

Tags: javascript, blur, gsap

I want to create some kind of zoom out animated effect using GSAP. What I'm trying to do is scaling an element from double its size to the normal size and apply a vanishing `blur filter`. The filter should start at `blur(15px)` and going down to `blur(0)`.

I thought I could do it this way:

```
var el = $('img');

TweenLite.set(el, {
  'webkitFilter': 'blur(15px)',
  scale: 2
});
TweenLite.to(el, 0, {
  autoAlpha: 1,
  delay: 1.75,
  ease: Power2.easeIn
}); 
TweenLite.to(el, 2, {
  'webkitFilter': 'blur(0px)',
  scale: 1,
  delay: 1.7,
  ease: Power2.easeIn
});
```

What happens, instead, is that the `blur(0)` gets applied immediately.

Here's a simple [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reZqJb) showing the problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried just updating to GSAP 1.18.4? Seems to work in your codepen. The CDN link to TweenMax 1.18.4 is https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.4/TweenMax.min.js

Comment: thanks, this actually worked. Why on the getting started page it still uses the 1.18.0?

Comment: There's an [example blur plugin](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/NWKjEBG) now.

Answer (score 2):

you can't really animate the blur filter, but you can set it. You can basically set up a timeline and use the progression of the timeline as the method to set the filter over the timeline duration.
below is update function that sets the blur over the timeline duration.

```
  onUpdate:function(tl){
    var tlp = (tl.progress()*40)>>0;
    TweenMax.set('#blur img',{'-webkit-filter':'blur(' + tlp + 'px' + ')','filter':'blur(' + tlp + 'px' + ')'});

      var heading = $('#blur h3');
    heading.text('blur(' + tlp + 'px)');
  }
```

here is a great demo made by Marzullo http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/ZWOmmg

Comment: I see. But you can't in GSAP, because with css3 you can animate it using keyframes, right?

Comment: yes, in CSS you can animate via Frames: .blur {
  -webkit-animation: blur 3s infinite;
}@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  0%, 100%  { -webkit-filter: blur(0px); }
  50% { -webkit-filter: blur(10px); }
}

Comment: Like @Jack posted above. With New `GSAP 1.8.4` you don't have to use `onUpdate` and can animate the CSS Filter directly. Please see this example:  http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/NNoWjw